# SimpleCV Image database import

Tags: database, image, import, simplecv

I am rather new to SimpleCV. I am running the newest version of SimpleCV on Windows Vista.
Question: How do I import a zip file containing images into SimpleCV?

The system works fine to import (1) single images on local drive and (2) url links, but I am not able to import a single folder (.zip) from local database into the system.
This is what I did:

machine_learning_data_set = "/Users/Arenzky/Desktop/testdataset.zip"

Can somebody please give me a clue what I am doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

At the moment we do not support loading zip files, although that could be added as a feature.  We can however load a directory of images.  So if you download and extract the the files, you can just load the directory by using:

```
from SimpleCV import ImageSet
imgs = ImageSet('/path/to/dir/images/')
```